# Evaluating the limit of $\ln(2x)/\ln(x)$ as $x\to\infty$

Tags: calculus

I'm trying to evaluate the following limit:

$\displaystyle\lim_{x \to \infty} \displaystyle\frac{\ln(2x)}{\ln(x)}$

Using L'Hospital's rule, I end up with:

$\displaystyle\lim_{x \to \infty} \displaystyle\frac{\frac{1}{x}}{\frac{2}{x}}$

= $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to \infty} x/2x$

= $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to \infty} 1/2$

= $1/2$

Is this correct?

Comment: It really helps readability if you format this using MathJax (see FAQ at top right). Regards –

Comment: I appreciate this. Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: no problem - when I first started. I also had to learn and it makes everything look beautiful! I had been used to a program that would do the LaTex and never had a good handle on it, but that was wrong of me - so this has forced me to learn more. Regards

Comment: @LeiLei Please change the $n$ to $x$. You overwrote Bob's edit because you started before he started, and he saved his edit, and then you saved your edit. You can refer to the revision history.

Comment: A tip that I found really cool when I first learned of it: If you just want to check if a solution works, you can type the problem in to wolfram alpha.  For an example, see this [link](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=limit%20%28ln%282x%29%29%2F%28lnx%29%20x%20to%20infinity&t=ff3tb01). (Spoiler alert: this is the question you asked, so only look *after* you solve it. `:)`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. You forgot to apply the chain rule when differentiating $\ln 2x$.

Also, I'm not sure where $n$ came from.

Answer (score 9):

HINT: No differentiation is needed:

$$\frac{\ln 2x}{\ln x}=\frac{\ln 2+\ln x}{\ln x}=1+\frac{\ln 2}{\ln x}$$

You **can** use l’Hospital’s rule here, but you have to differentiate $\ln 2x$ correctly.

Comment: Much simpler and easier!

Answer (score 3):

You answer is incorrect, and your should have checked this by experimentation. Putting $x=10^{10}$ gives $\ln(2x)/\ln x \approx 1.03$ while putting $x=10^{50}$ gives $\ln(2x)/\ln x \approx 1.01$. It would seem that $\ln(2x)/\ln x \to 1$ as $x \to \infty$. *However*, we need to prove this rigorously.

Simply apply the laws of logs: $\ln(ab) = \ln a + \ln b$. We see that

$$\frac{\ln (2x)}{\ln x} \equiv \frac{\ln 2 + \ln x}{\ln x} \equiv \frac{\ln 2}{\ln x}+1$$

Since $\ln x \to \infty$ as $x \to \infty$ it follows that $\ln(2x)/\ln x \to 1$ as $x \to \infty$.

If you insist upon using L'Hopital's rule then notice that:

\begin{array}{ccc}
\frac{\operatorname{d}}{\operatorname{d}\!x}\ln(2x) &=& \frac{2}{2x} \equiv \frac{1}{x} \\
\frac{\operatorname{d}}{\operatorname{d}\!x}\ln(x) &=& \frac{1}{x}
\end{array}

It follows that

$$\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{\ln(2x)}{\ln x} = \lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{1/x}{1/x} = 1$$